# Amazon streaming elastic mapreduce getting input file name and setting output

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services

I am using the amazon streaming function, is it possible to get the file input name?

Also can i set output so each new line isnt a new file?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using this correctly, if this is your question.  Your mapper should not care which file it's working on.  It gets a block of data from the entire set matching your --input argument, sends it to the mapper on the STDIN.  The mapper should process the input and output a **key**\t**val1**,**val2**,...  Those are then passed to (one of) your reducer on its STDIN.